# Dirty rects on a Canvas received from a SurfaceHolder's lockCanvas()

Tags: android, optimization, android-canvas

Is that possible? Because I need to draw a photo-background with moving objects on top of it, in atleast 35 fps. It must take alot of resources to redraw that whole background every frame, even for a short time? (live wallpaper)

I tried to redraw the background only at each moving object's Rect, but that only makes those parts of the screen flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems there is no big gain anyways in doing these opmimizations.

The flicker is ofcourse because of double-buffering, there are Two buffers to erase, therefore the flickering.